# grep help - search for this string: '$i['

Tags: regex, grep

I'm having trouble with using grep to search for the following string: **$i[**

I tried using this command:

```
grep -ir "$i\[" * > search.txt
```

I've added the \ to escape the square bracket.   Do I also need to escape the dollar sign symbol?

I'm using macOS terminal - which I believe is a Unix environment.

Anyway, what I want is the exact match for the sequence of characters above - it is okay if this string is contained within some other string.

To make clear what I am trying to describe I want this: ***$i[***  (where the * means wildcard or any character or whitespace on either side of **$i[**

But, for whatever reason I don't get exact matches containing $i[

The returned search results seem to include only the dollar sign and not the letter i next to the square bracket.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are searching for a fixed string, not a regex, you can use `-F` option with `grep`, and make sure you use single quotes to avoid any variable expansion:

```sh
grep -iFr '$i[' * > search.txt
```

If you still want to use a regex pattern, you need to escape both `[` (as it is used in regex to define the start of a bracket expression) and `$` (it is used to define the end of string position):

```sh
grep -ir '\$i\[' * > search.txt
```